# Allow access to a folder without access intermediary folders

Tags: permissions, acl

I would like to know if it's possible to give read access to a folder within another folder where the user hasn't access.
For example, a user needs to access all files within /folder1/folder2/folder3/logs without having access to read files or list any files within folder1 folder2 and folder3.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You only need to grant executable bit to these directories to make the user able of reading the log file, something like:

```
chmod -R ugo+x /folder1
```

With `+x` they can move into these directories however without the `r` (read) they can't list any files and they're only able to read a specific file which they have access to.

Comment: But then users can access any file in `/folder1` (provided they know or guess the name, which is rarely a problem).